# Using Webpart to replace logo

Tags: web-part

How do I change the sharepoint logo to add a picture and "welcome" Message?  Is this done in Web parts?

Answer (score 0):

No.  It is in Site Settings >> Title,Description,andIcon.

Upload an image to a library on the site.  Copy the URL of the image.  Go to the above location on the site.  Paste the URL of the image field and save.  Be mindful of image (not file) size.  Too big will drastically change your page look.

Comment: Do I need to  add the picture to my site assets?  If so, how do I do that?  I'm using 2010 SharePoint and I don't see site assets in the site settings.

Comment: It will be listed in your All Site Content.  If it is not, you can put the image in any library or make a new one (assets?)  Just use the URL of where you put it.  Be aware of the image size.

Comment: I've create site assets library and added the two logos. However can you provide some cleared directions to change the standard sharepoint logo.

Comment: updated answer with more instructions